# Expected number of 1's before a 6 shows up

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expectation

I have the following problem. How do I compute the expected number of 1s that will be seen by throwing a fair dice until a 6 turns up?

Comment: Take a look of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem **and any attempts you have made to solve it**. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Results of the die-rolling that are neither $1$ nor $6$ are irrelevant. So the answer is the same as the expected number of heads until a tail shows up, where the coin is fair.

You are probably familiar with the expected number of coin *tosses* up to *and including* the first tail.

**Remark:** Instead of using previous knowledge of the geometric distribution, we can attack the problem directly. Let $e$ be the expected number of $1$'s.

If the first toss is a $6$, then the expected number is $0$.

If the first number is one of $2,3,4,5$, then the expected number is $e$.

Finally, if the first toss is $1$, the expected number is $1+e$.

It follows that
$$e=0\cdot \frac{1}{6}+e\cdot\frac{4}{6}+(1+e)\cdot\frac{1}{6}.$$
This is a linear equation in $e$. Solve. We get $e=1$.

**Edit:** While I was typing the Remark, exactly the same argument, using proper conditional probability notation,  was posted in a comment by Ian.

Comment: You can prove the claim in the first sentence using the total expectation formula: if $X_n$ are iid "dice roll" random variables and $Y$ is the number of $1$s, then $E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^6 E(X|X_1=k)P(X_1=k)$. The last term is $0$, the middle four terms are each $E(X)/6$, and the first term is $(E(X)+1)/6$. So you get $E(X)=5E(X)/6+1/6$, which is easy to solve.